# Biber and Sublime text

Tags: biber, sublime-text

I use Sublime since two years and also biber but after an update of Latextools biber do not run. I get the two warnings below (and many more because of the undefined cites):

```
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:(biblatex)                Signalerzeugung(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

The console show me this:

```
<module 'simpleBuilder' from 'C:\\Users\\Dominik\\AppData\\Roaming\\Sublime Text 3\\Packages\\LaTeXTools\\builders\\simpleBuilder.py'>
<class 'simpleBuilder.SimpleBuilder'>
2
Welcome to thread Thread-9
['pdflatex', '-interaction=nonstopmode', '-synctex=1', 'Signalerzeugung']
Finished normally
0
False True True
!TEX root = 'D:\\Dropbox\\Masterarbeit\\dokumentation\\signalerzeugung\\Signalerzeugung.tex'
Jump to:  191 24
Windows, Calling Sumatra
```

I reinstalled  the latextools and Miktex but the Problem still exist :-(

Comment: Maybe it is in what order the packages are "called".

Comment: Which build routine do you use? What kind of routines does `SimpleBuilder` include?

Answer (score 1):

So, for future reference, this was answered [on the LaTeXTools issue tracker](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/issues/637).

To summarise, you have several options:

1. Using the traditional builder, which uses [`texify`](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/texify.html): Create an environment variable called `BIBTEX` ([Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10) or [more generally](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)) and set its value to `"biber"` or the path to your biber executable.
2. Install `latexmk` and change the `distro` setting in your LaTeXTools settings to `"texlive"`, which doesn't require that you have texlive installed.
3. Create a [custom builder](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/wiki/Custom-Builders) based on the `SimpleBuilder` that invokes `bibtex`. For reference it might look something like this:

   ```
   from pdfBuilder import PdfBuilder

   import re

   PDFLATEX = ["pdflatex", "-interaction=nonstopmode", "-synctex=1"]
   BIBER = ["biber"]

   CITATIONS_REGEX = re.compile(r"Warning: Citation `.+' on page \d+ undefined")

   class BiberBuilder(PdfBuilder):
       def __init__(self, *args):
           super(BiberBuilder, self).__init__(*args)
           self.name = "Biber Builder"

       def commands(self):
           self.display("\n\nBiberBuilder: ")

           yield(PDFLATEX + [self.base_name], "Running pdflatex...")
           self.display("done.\n")

           if CITATIONS_REGEX.search(self.out):
               yield(BIBER + [self.base_name], "Running biber...")
               self.display("done.\n")

               yield(PDFLATEX + [self.base_name], "Running pdflatex...")
               self.display("done.\n")

               yield(PDFLATEX + [self.base_name], "Running pdflatex...")
               self.display("done.\n")

           if "Rerun to get cross-references right." in self.out:
               yield (PDFLATEX + [self.base_name], "Running pdflatex...")
               self.display("done.\n")
   ```

   Save the builder to a file called `biberBuilder.py` in a folder underneath Sublime Packages directory (in Sublime select **Preferences|Browse Packages...**) and set the `"builder_path"` setting in your LaTeXTools settings to the relative path to the folder containing the builder, e.g. `"User/LaTeXTools"` and set the `"builder"` setting to `"biber"`