# Empty bibliography: Sublime

Tags: bibliographies, overleaf, sublime-text

Sublime doesn't load my bibliography

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[%
natbib=true,backend=biber,sorting=nymdt,%
maxbibnames=150,%
citestyle=apa,bibstyle=apa,%
url=false,doi=false,isbn=false%
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\begin{document}
\input{CHAPTERS/chapter_1.tex}
\cleardoublepage 
\printbibliography
\cleardoublepage 
\end{document}
```

I get this error:

> LaTex Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 80 (at `\addbibresource{test.bib}`)

I found similar problems online but I really cannot grasp the issue here, because my script works perfectly fine on Overleaf, it's only Sublime that gives me this issue.

Did anyone else experienced this asymmetry between Overleaf and Sublime and knows how to make Sublime work?

Comment: Do your citations just show the keys in bold? Probably you need to be running `biber` on your file as well as latex, see [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/106162). [Biber and Sublime text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286095/106162) might help with configuring Sublime

Comment: How are you compiling within Sublime?